# Max (formerly HBOMax) streaming error under 20.04 / Firefox 104

Tags: firefox, streaming

I'm using Firefox 104 under Ubuntu 20.04.  After HBOMax became Max, attempts to stream videos using Firefox result in an error message: "Something went wrong". Changing the Firefox User Agent to Chromium for Windows does not resolve the problem.  I installed Chromium, but it doesn't work either.  Has anyone else experienced the problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Use Chrome or Opera-env. Both have all the proprietary tools needed to playback DRM video.

Open source browser are not likely to ever have DRM in them unless you install/activate it yourself. Firefox, when using Netflix, Prime, Disney, F1TV.com, prompts you if it needs DRM enabled but with HBO that does not happen so likely it is a DRM not provided by Firefox. I myself have yet to get HBO working. Maybe in time it will.

Comment: Thanks.  I installed Google Chrome, and it streams successfully (though I only tested with the first few minutes of a video).

Comment: that will be enough :)